# Are mixed boundary conditions possible in structural mechanics?

Tags: boundary-conditions, solid-mechanics

For structural mechanics, such as linear elasticity, I am aware of BCs such as a prescribed displacement (Dirichlet) or a prescribed traction (Neumann).

Is it possible that a boundary can have a mixture of prescribed displacement and prescribed traction, i.e., a mixture of Dirichlet and Neumann BCs for the same boundary? It would seem that this would make the problem over-specified?

Comment: Are you talking about mixed boundary conditions, like Robin? 
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_boundary_condition

Comment: @AntonMenshov Yes, I think so. If not, then at least it is analogous to that. I am trying to picture how this would even work in structures, and I cannot think of how it would.

Comment: One thing is having Robin boundary conditions (a linear combination of displacements and tractions) and another one is to have both displacement and tractions prescribed over a region. Which case are you interested in?

Comment: Could you give an example of each? I guess I am not seeing how the two can be applied to the same boundary.

Comment: The mixed (Robin) condition states that there is a linear relationship between the traction and the displacement, i.e. some kind of spring-type boundary condition.

Comment: as another interpretation, you can have simultaneous traction and displacement in different vector orientations at a point or over a surface.

Comment: If a structure had a roller support at part of its boundary, would this be considered a mixed BC?

Comment: A roller imposes displacement in one direction and imposes (free) traction in the other one.

Answer (score 2):

You can't prescribe *both* Dirichlet and Neumann conditions, but you can prescribe a Robin-type boundary condition in which the normal stress (traction) is proportional to the displacement. You can think of this as a case where each point at the boundary is tethered by a little spring to its undeformed location, with the springs producing a force that is proportional to the displacement from the undeformed configuration. An example of how this could be done is when your body is in contact with another body.